# How to add email address to firebase kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I can't add email address with **@** & **.com** to the firebase. App gets closed.  This's the code I used.

```
 val FullName = FullName.getText().toString()
                    val PhoneNo = PhoneNo.getText().toString().toInt()
                    val Age = Age.getText().toString().toInt()
                    val EmailAddress = EmailAddress.getText().toString()
                    val BankAccNo = BankAccNo.getText().toString()
                    val PasswordRegister = PasswordRegister.getText().toString()

                    val User = User(FullName,PhoneNo,Age,EmailAddress, BankAccNo,PasswordRegister)
                    myRef.child(EmailAddress).setValue(User)
```

others are working properly.
Here's the data class of **User**

```
data class User(val FullName: String, val PhoneNo:Int,
                val Age:Int, val EmailAddress:String,  val BankAccNo:String, val PasswordRegister:String)
```

[image: This's the error what I get]

[image: This's the line 46]

edited. it got error in **dataSnapshot.child(decodeUserEmail).child("passwordRegister").getValue(String::class.java)** line

```
 fun decodeUserEmail(email: String) = email.replace(",", ".")
    
    private fun isUser() {
        val  userEnteredEmail = email.getText().toString().trim()
        val  userEnteredPassword = password1.getText().toString().trim()
        
        val decodeUserEmail = decodeUserEmail(userEnteredEmail)

        val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")

        val checkUser: Query = reference.orderByChild("emailAddress").equalTo(decodeUserEmail)

        checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(@NonNull dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    val passwordFromDB =
                        dataSnapshot.child(decodeUserEmail).child("passwordRegister").getValue(String::class.java)
                    if (passwordFromDB.equals(userEnteredPassword)) {
                        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, Home::class.java))

                        val intent = Intent(baseContext, Home::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", decodeUserEmail)
                        startActivity(intent)

                    } else {

                    }

                } else{
                }

            }
            override fun onCancelled(@NonNull databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
        })
```

Comment: Kindly share the stack trace. With the current information, we can't help you much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error sais:

> Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'`

This means that Firebase does not allow you to use those symbols in the key names. So instead of using the email address as a key for the user's node, I recommend you to use the UID:

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
currentUser?.apply {
    myRef.child(uid).setValue(User)
}
```

It's always better such an approach because the UID it's always the same. The email address can be changed by the user.

If you don't want to use this approach, then you might consider encoding the email address like this:

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

To achieve this, I recommend you using the following methods:

```
fun encodeUserEmail(userEmail: String) = userEmail.replace(".", ",")

fun decodeUserEmail(userEmail: String) = userEmail.replace(",", ".")
```

**Edit:**

```
val encodedEmail = encodeUserEmail(EmailAddress)
myRef.child(encodedEmail).setValue(User)
```

Comment: If don't mind, Can u tell me how to use this second method? Actually I'm new to Kotlin

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Does it work?

Comment: Is decodedEmail also same as above ? to get from firebase

Comment: Yes, indeed. You should do it in the same way.

Comment: But it got errors. I updated it in the Question

Comment: If you want to read the node where the `name@email,com` exists, you need to add the encoded email in the path, not in a query. Most likely `.equalTo(decodeUserEmail)` doesn't satisfy that condition.

Comment: It doesn't work. no errors but can't open activity after login

Comment: That's most likely another issue that causes that. It's hard to say without seeing the exact code that you are using. So please post a new question, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.