# Cannot add data to different nodes in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

In Firebase Realtime Database, already have **user** node. I need to create another node named **BankDetails** but when I try to enter details It gets an error. not created Another node.

[image: Firebase]

[image: New Created Bank Details]

Here's My code. It's on the fragment.

```
val database = Firebase.database
    val myRef = database.getReference("BankDetails")
```

```
 view.rechargeAmount.setOnClickListener {

            if( emailBankText.text.trim().isNotEmpty()) {
                val bankAccNo = bankAccText.getText().toString()
                val accountBalance = amountText.getText().toString().toDouble()

                val encodedEmail = encodeUserEmail(emailBankText.toString())
                val bankDetails1 = BankDetails(encodedEmail,bankAccNo,accountBalance)
                myRef.child(encodedEmail).setValue(bankDetails1).addOnSuccessListener {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


                } .addOnFailureListener{

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "not updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }
            }

            else{
                Toast.makeText(activity, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
```

This's the error I got `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path` Is there anything wrong in my code. Help me, I'm new to Kotlin.

**edit**

I created another node and add some test data. [image: Like this]  but

[image: I still got this error]

Comment: Have you tried to change `val database = Firebase.database` to `val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()`?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yaa, and got same error. Is there not other way to add data to BankDetails node?

Comment: Are you sure that the `encodedEmail` has a value without a `.`? Can you check that?

Comment: @AlexMamo You're right. That's the matter. Thank You so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is due to the use of a `.` inside a value that will be added as a key in the Realtime Database, which is actually not possible. You should always encode the email address to:

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

As explained in my answer from the following post:

> [How to add email address to firebase kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326157/how-to-add-email-address-to-firebase-kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

`BankDetails` does not exist, so `myRef` variable cannot be initialized because they can't find this node, you need to create this node by adding some test data inside the node and then the problem should be fixed.

Comment: Still Problem not solved

Comment: I updated my question again

Comment: @ABI You have only one database on your firebase project?